# nitrous.io and mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, nitrousio

I've installed MySQL using the instructions on nitrous.io using autoparts.  Once installed and running, is it possible to use your local MySQL workbench to connect to the MySQL Server installed on that nitrous.io environment?

So you could ssh into your nitrous.io box from your local machine, but can you do the same and connect to MySQL using your local machine?  If so, what credentials would you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MySQL Workbench and other apps if you establish SSH tunneling with your Nitrous box. Run the following command in your Unix console, replacing the variables with the actual values found on your boxes page:

```
ssh -N -p <box_port> action@<box_host> -L <local_port>/localhost/<remote_port>
```

From there you can open up MySQL Workbench and connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 3306. You will also need to ensure your MySQL database on Nitrous is running. Run `parts start mysql` to start up the database.

Take a look at the [Nitrous.IO guide](http://help.nitrous.io/sql-database-management/) for a complete walkthrough.